Timer Extension Does Not Work After Upload but Works While Unpacked
I have a background script to track time for a time tracking extension. And the main feature is to be able to work on the background when the popup windows is closed.
The issue is when I load unpacked it works fine without an issue but when I publish it and add into my chrome, the timer doesn't work. The manifest is in V3.
Here is my background.js code:
// background.js

chrome.alarms.create({
  periodInMinutes: 1 / 60,
});

let timerInterval;
let timerValue = 0;

chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener((alarm) => {
  chrome.storage.local.get(["timer", "isRunning"], (res) => {
      const time = res.timer ?? 0;
      const isRunning = res.isRunning ?? true;
      if (!isRunning) {
          return;
      }
      chrome.storage.local.set({
          timer: time + 1,
      });
      chrome.action.setBadgeText({
          text: `${time + 1}`
      });
  });
});

chrome.runtime.onSuspend.addListener(() => {
  clearInterval(timerInterval); // Stop the timer interval when the extension is suspended
  timerValue = 0; // Reset the timer value
  chrome.action.setBadgeText({ text: "" }); // Clear the badge
});

chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
  if (timerInterval) {
      clearInterval(timerInterval);
      timerValue = 0;
      chrome.action.setBadgeText({ text: "" }); // Clear the badge when timer is stopped
      timerInterval = null;
  } else {
      timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
          timerValue++;
          chrome.action.setBadgeText({ text: timerValue.toString() });
      }, 1000);
  }
});

I also noticed when I unpacked the one in my PC while I have the one from the store, both works fine again (it is like the unpacked one executes something and due to that the one from store works also) but when I remove the unpacked, the published one doesn't track again. How can I solve this issue? Thank you in advance!

The background script unloads after 30 seconds, see Persistent Service Worker in Chrome Extension.
